# Fill this missing name from Column C Excel Formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have list of data where `Column A` has Duplicate ID's. In the Column B where you see the `Text Searched` which `Name` is empty that needs to be fill.

I am looking for a formula which takes the `Name` from `Column C` where there is last `Viewed Page` value in `Column B` for similar `ID` in `Column A` which Name is empty.

Take the `Name`and paste in Column D. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

[Download copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15dw5hONN4MB00hpWy7gRPtpqp1_TrsaiImfQdTmVfKw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Office 365, try:

```
D2: =IF(C3<>"","",LET(
      x, FILTER($C$2:C3,($A$2:A3=A3)*($B$2:B3="Viewed Page")),
      y, COUNTA(x),INDEX(x,y)))
```

*and fill down*

If you have an older version, try:

```
D2: =IF(C2<>"","",INDEX($C$1:C1,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($A$2:A2=A2)*($B$2:B2="Viewed Page"))*ROW($B$2:B2),1)))
```

Note the array argument for the `INDEX` function starts at `C1` and not `C2`.  This is because the `AGGREGATE` function is returning the absolute row number, and not the index into the array.

Comment: Thank you for solution but i uave Excel 2016.

Comment: @Strenuous See my edit for a version that should work in 2016